# how to prevent a "div" tagged to the first dropdown menu from hiding itself once I select an option on second dropdown menu on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'll try to explain as best as I could on the issue I am facing.

Basically there are 3 dropdown menus dropDownGroup1, dropDownGroup2, and dropDownGroup3 on the same page, where once a user selects an option from for example, dropdownGroup1 a div that is tagged to the selected option will show.

The problem I'm facing currently is that every time I select an option from the other 2 dropdown menu afterwards , the div that appeared when I selected on dropdownGroup1 hides itself. how do I prevent that from happening. I tried grouping them but the jquery doesn't seem to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class^='dropDownValue']").click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var parents = $(this).parents(".dropDownGroup");
    var targetBox = parents.find("." + inputValue);
    parents.find('.dropdownOptions').not(targetBox).addClass('d-none');
    parents.find(targetBox).removeClass('d-none');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownGroup1">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue1">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option1" id="01">Option1</option>
      <option value="Option2" id="02">Option2</option>
      <option value="Option3" id="03">Option3</option>
      <option value="Option4" id="04">Option4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option1 dropdownOptions d-none">Option1</div>
  <div class="Option2 dropdownOptions d-none">Option2</div>
  <div class="Option3 dropdownOptions d-none">Option3</div>
  <div class="Option4 dropdownOptions d-none">Option4</div>
</div>

<div class="dropDownGroup2">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue2">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option5" id="05">Option5</option>
      <option value="Option6" id="06">Option6</option>
      <option value="Option7" id="07">Option7</option>
      <option value="Option8" id="08">Option8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option5 dropdownOptions d-none">Option5</div>
  <div class="Option6 dropdownOptions d-none">Option6</div>
  <div class="Option7 dropdownOptions d-none">Option7</div>
  <div class="Option8 dropdownOptions d-none">Option8</div>
</div>

<div class="dropDownGroup3">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue3">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option9" id="09">Option5</option>
      <option value="Option10" id="10">Option6</option>
      <option value="Option11" id="11">Option7</option>
      <option value="Option12" id="12">Option8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option9 dropdownOptions d-none">Option9</div>
  <div class="Option10 dropdownOptions d-none">Option10</div>
  <div class="Option11 dropdownOptions d-none">Option11</div>
  <div class="Option12 dropdownOptions d-none">Option12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "*hides itself*" - does it?  Or is it your code that's hiding it?  And you need to add an exclusion (like you do for other exclusions already)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use closest div from your select-box and then use `.siblings` to hide/show only div where value matches.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.custom-select").change(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val(); //get value
    console.log(inputValue)
    var parents = $(this).closest(".form-group");
    var targetBox = parents.siblings("." + inputValue);
    parents.siblings('.dropdownOptions').not(targetBox).addClass('d-none'); //hide other siblings...
    targetBox.removeClass('d-none'); //show 
  });
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropDownGroup1">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue1">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option1" id="01">Option1</option>
      <option value="Option2" id="02">Option2</option>
      <option value="Option3" id="03">Option3</option>
      <option value="Option4" id="04">Option4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option1 dropdownOptions d-none">Option1</div>
  <div class="Option2 dropdownOptions d-none">Option2</div>
  <div class="Option3 dropdownOptions d-none">Option3</div>
  <div class="Option4 dropdownOptions d-none">Option4</div>
</div>

<div class="dropDownGroup2">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue2">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option5" id="05">Option5</option>
      <option value="Option6" id="06">Option6</option>
      <option value="Option7" id="07">Option7</option>
      <option value="Option8" id="08">Option8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option5 dropdownOptions d-none">Option5</div>
  <div class="Option6 dropdownOptions d-none">Option6</div>
  <div class="Option7 dropdownOptions d-none">Option7</div>
  <div class="Option8 dropdownOptions d-none">Option8</div>
</div>

<div class="dropDownGroup3">
  <div class="form-group ">
    <label>Lorem Ipsum</label>
    <select class="custom-select dropDownValue3">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="Option9" id="09">Option9</option>
      <option value="Option10" id="10">Option10</option>
      <option value="Option11" id="11">Option11</option>
      <option value="Option12" id="12">Option12</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="Option9 dropdownOptions d-none">Option9</div>
  <div class="Option10 dropdownOptions d-none">Option10</div>
  <div class="Option11 dropdownOptions d-none">Option11</div>
  <div class="Option12 dropdownOptions d-none">Option12</div>
</div>
```